# Trying to put my header button in the center of the page

Tags: html, css

Trying to put my header button in the center of the page

This is my css:

```
header div {

 height: 250px;
 width:950px;
 background-color: white;
 border-width: 5px;
 border-style: solid dark-blue 5px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin: auto;
 padding-top: 50px;
 clear: both;
 float: center;
 vertical-align: middle;

}
```

my html:

```
<header>
    <div> <img src="test.png"> </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***update***
As you added your code (in an answer?) i see what you want and here is what you want:

```css
.gradient {

  /* can be treated like a fallback */
  background-color: #F8F8FF;

  /* will be "on top", if browser supports it */
  background-image: linear-gradient(#F8F8FF, #00BFFF);

  /* these will reset other properties, like background-position, but it does know what you mean */
  background: #F8F8FF;
  background: linear-gradient(#F8F8FF, #00BFFF);

}



* {
    /* Reset the default styles. 
    Use border-box because it's easier! */
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background:#DCDCDC;
  color:aliceblue;
  font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight:300;
  margin:0 auto;
  
  /* Click-and-drag or text-selection doesn't make sense. */
  /* Or long-tap on webkit phones. */
  -webkit-touch-callout:none;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
  -khtml-user-select:none;
  -moz-user-select:none;
  -ms-user-select:none;
  user-select:none;
}

main {
  /* Use a max-width so that we have 4 columns */
  max-width:680px;
  margin:auto;
  padding:20px;
}

header  {
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 5px 36px 5px;
  font-size:24px;
  background:white;
}

ul {
  /* We don't need actual bullets */
  list-style:none;
}

li {
  float:left; /* So that they wrap */
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  margin:5px; /* The gaps between them */
  
  text-transform:capitalize;
  
  /*transition may need prefixes in some browsers */
  -webkit-transition:.2s -webkit-transform, 1s opacity;
  -moz-transition:   .2s -moz-transform, 1s opacity;
  -o-transition:     .2s -o-transform, 1s opacity;
  transition:        .2s transform, 1s opacity;
  
  /*transform*/
  -webkit-transform:perspective(800px);
  -moz-transform:perspective(800px);
  -ms-transform:perspective(800px);
  -o-transform:perspective(800px);
  transform:perspective(800px);
  
  /*transform-style*/
  -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style:preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style:preserve-3d;
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin-x:50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin-y:50%;
  
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
}

/* When moused over, rotate it! */
li:active {
  /*transform*/
  -webkit-transform:perspective(800px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 17deg);
  -moz-transform:perspective(800px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 17deg);
  -ms-transform:perspective(800px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 17deg);
  -o-transform:perspective(800px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 17deg);
  transform:perspective(800px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 17deg);
}

/* It'd be neat to have double-width tiles */
.span2{
  width:310px;
}

/* Icon and number */
li i{
  font-size:60px;
  margin:35px 0 0;
}

/* Text label on tiles */
li span{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:8px;
  left:8px;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}

/* Specialized background colours */
.smartwatches{
  background:yellow;
  color: black;
  }
.tabletpc{
  background:rgb(27, 161, 226);
}
.inktoner{
  background:rgb(240, 163, 10);
}
.kenton{
  background:rgb(119, 158, 203);
}
.Healthfitness{
  background:rgb(0, 80, 239);
}
.accessories{
  background:rgb(119, 221, 119);
}
.cellc{
  background:rgb(0, 192, 0);
}
.mweb{
  background:rgb(27, 161, 226);
}
.messages{
  background:rgb(240, 163, 10);
}
.contacts{
  background:rgb(119, 158, 203);
}
.internet{
  background:rgb(0, 80, 239);
}
.maps{
  background:rgb(119, 221, 119);
}
.jobcard{
  background:rgb(130, 111, 214);
}
.asktechguy{
  background:rgb(100, 118, 135);
}
.register{
  background:rgb(255, 105, 97);
}
.agentsreseller{
  background:rgb(162, 0, 37);
}

header {
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
    border: solid blue 5px;
}
header div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


footer div {
     height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: solid darkblue 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  clear: both;
  float: center;
    }
```

```html
<!-- ontouchstart makes :active work in mobile Safari -->
<body ontouchstart="" class="gradient" >
<main>
<header>
    <div> <img src="img.png" /> </div>
</header>  
    <!-- Now make the tiles! -->
    <!-- Use the <i> to make the icon and number -->
    <!-- Move the <span>s in CSS so they appear in the bottom left corner -->
    <ul>
        <li class="smartwatches"><i class="fa fa-smart-watches"> <img src=""/> </i><span> <a href="#"> Smart Watches<a/></span></li>
        <li class="tabletpc"><i class="fa fa-tabletpc"> <img src=""/> </i><span> <a href="#">Tablet pc's</a></span></li>
        <li class="inktoner"><i class="fa fa-inktoner"> <img src=""/> </i><span>Ink & Toner</span></li>
        <li class="kenton"><i class="fa fa-kenton"> <img src=""/> </i><span> <a href="#">Kenton products</a></span></li>
        <li class="Healthfitness"><i class="fa fa-healthfitness"> <img src=""/> </i><span> <a href="#">Health & Fitness</a></span></li>
        <li class="Accessories"><i class="fa fa-accessories"> <img src=""/> </i><span> <a href="#">Accessories</a></span></li>
        <li class="cellc"><i class="fa fa-cellc"> <img style="position: absolute; top: 15px; left:20px; right:20"src="http://logo.jpg" height="80px" width="100px"/> </i><span><a href="http://e-clearexpress.co.za/store/index.php/cellc"> CellC Deals </a></span> </li>
        <li class="mweb"><i class="fa fa-mweb"> <img style="position: absolute; top: 15px; left:20px; right:20" src="http://eeb-logo.jpg" height="80px" width="100px"/></i><span><a href="http://e-cleab"> WEB </a></span></li>
        <li class="photos"><i class="fa fa-instagram"> <img src=""/></i><span><a href="#"> Smart Watches<a/></span></li>
        <li class="settings"><i class="fa fa-gears"> <img src=""/></i><span><a href="#"> Smart Watches<a/></span></li>
  <li class="phone"><i class="fa fa-phone"> <img src=""/></i><span><a href="#"> Smart Watches<a/></span></li>
        <li class="messages"><i class="fa fa-comments">  <img src=""/></i><span><a href="#"> Smart Watches<a/></span></li>
        <li class="jobcard"><i class="fa fa-jobcard"> <img src=""/></i><span><a href="#"> Job Card Bookings<a/></span></li>
        <li class="asktechguy"><i class="fa fa-asktechguy"> <img src=""/></i><span><a href="#"> Ask Tech Guy<a/></span></li>
        <li class="register"><i class="fa fa-register"> <img src=""/></i><span><a href="#"> Register here<a/></span></li>
        <li class="agentsresellers"><i class="fa fa-map-agentsresellers"> <img src=""/></i><span><a href="#"> Agents & Resellers<a/></span></li>
    </ul>
</main>
<footer>
<div>
<p></p> 
<p> All rights reserved E-C </p>
<p> Designed by <a href="http://www..co.za"> Eng</a> </p>
</div>
 </footer>
            </body>
```

---

Just use css attribute [text-align](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp).

```
text-align: center;
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/g7hecLjo/

Comment: that aligns the text not the box

Comment: it aligns the content of the div, thats what i think you asked for? an image in the div will be centered. 
Or do you want to put in centered vertically and horizontally as well?

Comment: just in case you wanted the box centered horizonally and vertically: http://jsfiddle.net/5076oL4k/

Answer (score 1):

`float` takes only three values: `left`, `right` and `none`.

Change the `float: center` to `text-align: center` and replace `border-width: 5px; border-style: solid dark-blue 5px;` with `border: 5px solid darkblue;`

```css
header div {
    height: 250px;
    width:950px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 5px solid darkblue;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" />
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: @user4285276, and? isn't it work? Press the `Run code snippet` above to check, that all works here.

Comment: for view the box, need to correct `border-style` to `border` :)

Comment: @vp_arth - True! I totally missed that. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know y cos i have a button as a footer nd that one is center, i copied that coding and put it for my header and it goes right

Comment: see i reposted my entire html and css under answers

Answer (score 0):

There is no float:center.

try something like this:

```
<div class="outer">

  <div class="inner">
     <img src="somwhere.html">  <!-- this will be centered -->
  </div>

</div>
```

the CSS

```
div.outer {
  text-align:center;
}

div.inner {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

display:inline-block causes the inner div to shrink-wrap the image (or whatever you want to center). The text-align:center; moves it to the middle of the outer full-width div. HTH.

Also while the simple text-align:center works for inline elements, the technique I show here allows you to center block level elements such as menus created from unordered lists.

Comment: i know how to align the image, i need to align the box, let me try it though

Comment: I don't know y cos i have a button as a footer nd that one is center, i copied that coding and put it for my header and it goes right

Answer (score 0):

user4285276, I have encountered this exact problem on numerous sites of mine. Many of the other answers are more complex than they need to be, so I’d recommend trying this method first. Let me tell you how to center an image, regardless of a div, nav, or header around it, and then we can work from there. The CSS needed to center a single item is very simple.

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -Xpx
}
```

In this code, X is equal to half of the width of your image or other object. So the code for your image if it was 100 pixels wide would show X as 50.

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px
}
```

In other words, this code tells the image to move halfway across the page, then move half of the image’s width back towards the side of the page, centering it perfectly. To execute this in your code, do the following steps.

A. Set header width to 100%.
B. Add the following code to the div nested within your header, where X is equal to half of your div’s width.

```
div header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -Xpx
}
```

C. Add the same code to the image nested within your div, where X is equal to half of it’s width.

```
#yourimage {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -Xpx
}
```

So at the end of all this, your basic HTML would look like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div>
                <img id="yourimage" src="image.png">
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

...and your CSS would look like this:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
}

header div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -200px;
}

#yourimage {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -50px;
}
```